# VerificationException when using Unity in Web Player mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, smartfoxserver

I'm working on a web project that uses Unity3D and SmartFox and I'm having trouble with a specific setting. Whenever my editor is set to "Web Player", I get the following exception:

```
VerificationException: Error verifying Sfs2X.Logging.LoggerEvent:LogEventType (Sfs2X.Logging.LogLevel): Object not compatible with constrained type at 0x000e
```

Which is thrown on the 2nd line:

```
SmartFox server = new SmartFox (true);
server.AddLogListener(logLevel, (EventListenerDelegate)OnDebugMessage);
```

(And if I omit that line, it is thrown anytime I call a method from the server variable)

It works if I build in Standalone mode. It also works on another colleague's computer (Web mode), but I can't find any difference in our project settings.

Reading about the exception didn't help much, except that it is thrown whenever you write unverifiable code and try to compile it to a safe(?) binary. I couldn't find anything else about the other parts of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else looking, Luke got an answer from Smartfox forums:

http://www.smartfoxserver.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=17686

> Going back to Mono Develop 4.0.1 (delivered with Unity) fixes the
>   issue. If you are still struggling with this issue contact us by email
>   so we can provide a fixed dll.